# Looking for a test tool for Flash-based web applications. Any ideas?

Tags: automated-testing, flash

I'm looking for a Selenium-like tool to test Flash-based web applications (specifically a guided interview with questions and form fields that the user navigates through to produce a document at the end). I would like to create automated scripts with set content to run through the tools for QA purposes.

Answer (score 3):

There is [flex-ui-selenium](http://code.google.com/p/flex-ui-selenium/) and [flash selenium](http://code.google.com/p/flash-selenium/); both extensions to existing selenium RC adding flash communication capabilities to it.

Another quiet interesting tool with which some people around me have gone much farther is [RIAtest](http://www.riatest.com/). Its similar to the unit testing framework for flex called flex-unit but is used for GUI automation.

and finally I have remotely heard of [flex monkey](http://flexmonkey.gorillalogic.com/) (yet anoter gui automation tool)

Comment: I've used all 3 with limited success.  Flex Monkey was by far the best in my own opinion, although depending on the application that you're testing, you may need to also purchase a flash builder license.

Answer (score 0):

FlexMonkium is also an option. FlexMonkium: FlexMonkey Plugin for Selenium. It comes with a IDE in firefox for record and playback of Flash based sites. Prerequisite is you need to compile your flash application with the libraries provided for the objects to be recognised

Some links to check are http://www.gorillalogic.com/testing-tools/flexmonkium/flexmonkium-docs/flexmonkey-setup

A good tutorial collection is available in http://www.jamesward.com/2011/03/02/testing-flex-apps-with-flexmonkey-reloaded/