# What tools are available for automated testing of Flex/HTML5?

Tags: automated-testing, tools, flash, silktest

I have been tasked with implementing automated testing for a `web portal`. The product is currently developed using `Flex`, but we will be transitioning to `HTML5` at some point. My supervisors want a tool, that will work for both `Flex` and `HTML5`. Another intern and I have been unable to get `Silk Test` to work with `Flex`, and I'm confused as to what options exist.

My questions:

- Are there any free options that might be a better fit than `SilkTest`?

Comment: search shows: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1250/looking-for-a-test-tool-for-flash-based-web-applications-any-ideas http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1450/flex-test-automation-tools-questions http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/3161/what-is-the-most-appropriate-tool-to-perfrom-test-automation-of-adobe-air-applic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SmartBear TestComplete 9` now works with both.

https://smartbear.com/product/testcomplete/overview/

Answer (score 2):

`MonkeyTalk` (former `FlexMonkey`) works with both as well.

http://www.gorillalogic.com/testing-tools/monkeytalk

Answer (score 0):

`RIATest` works with `Flex` and `HTML5`:

http://www.cogitek.com/riatest.html